# Writing arbitrary type instances into a MemoryStream in C#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, serialization, memorystream

In Delphi, one can do the following:

```
var
  ms  : TMemoryStream;
  i   : Integer;
begin
  ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
  i := 1024;
  ms.Write(@i, SizeOf(Integer));
  ms.Free;
end;
```

This will write the memory contents of i into ms.

The .Net version of MemoryStream doesn't have such a feature (neither the managed nor unmanaged versions). I know .Net doesn't work on the same principles as Delphi in this regard.

How does one do this in C#? I am interested in the "best practice" and the fastest methods.

Comment: SizeOf() is determined by the compiler, not at runtime. This style of serialization is blazingly fast and simple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using [BinaryWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binarywriter.aspx) on top of MemoryStream:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(); 
BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(memoryStream);
writer.Write((int)123);
```

Note: don't forget to Dispose streams and writers/readers in real code, i.e. by `using` .

Comment: You forgot to link the stream to the writer.

Answer (score 7):

You can *Serialize* your object to a byte array

```
// Convert an object to a byte array
private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        return null;
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}

// Convert a byte array to an Object
private Object ByteArrayToObject(byte[] arrBytes)
{
    MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
    BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
    memStream.Write(arrBytes, 0, arrBytes.Length);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    Object obj = (Object) binForm.Deserialize(memStream);
    return obj;
}
```

And then use `MemoryStream` to write it as wanted

```
byte[] mData = ObjectToByteArray(myObject);
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
memStream.write(mData, 0, mData.Length);
```

EDIT:
If you want to write an integer, use

```
byte[] mData = BitConverter.GetBytes((UInt16)iInteger);
memStream.write(mData, 0, mData.Length);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is serializing the whole object, not just the value. So an integer is being stored as 36 bytes. I only want the value 4.

Answer (score 2):

.NET streams only deal with `byte` data.

To write any other kind of data, you need an 'endpiece':

- BinaryWriter to write primitive values (int, double, string)
- TextWriter to write char and lines, using an Encoding
- A Serializer (many choicess) to write objects

So in your case:

```
var writer = new BinaryWriter(myStream);
writer.Write(i);  // writes 4 bytes only
```

Comment: thank you for explaining what to use when. Makes sense to me now.